# The difference between Class#define_method and Module#define_method

Tags: ruby

Because I found `:define_method` appears both in `Class.private_instance_methods` and `Module.private_instance_methods`.Can you tell me why? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because it's defined in Module: http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/define_method and base class of Class is Module. So, if that what you ask, you can use both.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I have already know this.I Originally thought the method private_instance_methods return the private methods that not include the private methods of its ancestors.But I'm wrong.

Comment: signature is `private_instance_methods(include_super = true)` (the same as for other introspection methods).

Answer (score 0):

`define_method` is defined in `Module`.

`Class` *inherits* from `Module`. And therefore `#define_method`.

Simplified: A Class is just a module, *but you can instantiate a Class* (a module not).